# Rendering an image from my backend to my front

Tags: node.js, reactjs, multer

In my backend, I have server.ts which uses fileUpload.
I also have FileUpload.ts that uses multer, to save images in my backend server on a folder called "Images" (This works, saves the images with the item's ID at the beginning)

[image]

this is my server.ts:

```
const server = express();
server.use(cors());
server.use(express.json());

server.use("/api/v1/vacations", router);
server.use("/api/v1/users", userRoutes);

console.log("check if tables exist..");

server.use("*", ErrorHandler);
server.use(fileUpload);
//use express.static to server images under "Images" folder as static content
// server.use("/Images", express.static("Images"));
server.use("/Images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "Images")));
server.get("/Images/:image", (req, res) => {
  const fileName = req.params.image;
  console.log(__dirname + "/Images" + fileName);
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/Images/" + fileName);
});
```

this is my FileUpload.ts (multer):

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "Images");
  },
  filename: async (req, file, cb) => {
    const vacationId = req.params.id;
    const originalName = file.originalname.split(".")[0];
    const ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
    const fileName = `${vacationId}_${originalName}${ext}`;
    console.log(fileName);
    console.log(path.join(__dirname, "../Images", fileName));
    cb(null, fileName);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

this is my route when adding a vacation, for routing to the multer to save the image:

```
router.post(
  "/:id/upload",
  upload.single("image"),
  (request: Request, response: Response) => {
    response.send("image uploaded successfully");
  }
);
```

this is my SingleVacation:

```
interface singleVacationProps {
  id?: number;
  destination: string;
  vacDesc: string;
  vacPrice: number;
  vacImg: string;
}

function SingleVacation(props: singleVacationProps): JSX.Element {
  console.log(`SingleVac: , ${props.id}_${props.vacImg}`);
  return (
    <div className="SingleVacation">
      <Card>
        <CardHeader>{props.destination}</CardHeader>
        <CardMedia
          component="img"
          src={`http://localhost:4000/Images/${props.id}_${props.vacImg}`}
          alt={`${props.destination}`}
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography>{props.vacDesc}</Typography>
          <Typography>{props.vacPrice}</Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and this is VacationList:

```
function VacationList(): JSX.Element {
  const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const vacations = useSelector(
    (state: { vacations: { vacations: Vacation[] } }) =>
      state.vacations.vacations
  );
  console.log("Vacations: ", vacations);
  useEffect(() => {
    //use redux
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/api/v1/vacations/list")
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({
          type: VacationActionType.downloadVacations,
          payload: response.data,
        });
        console.log("Dispatched action:", {
          type: downloadVacations,
          payload: response.data,
        });
      });
    // setRefresh(false);
  }, [dispatch]);
  return (
    <div className="VacationList">
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        {vacations.map((item) => (
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
            <SingleVacation
              key={item.id}
              id={item.id}
              destination={item.destination}
              vacDesc={item.vacDesc}
              vacImg={item.vacImg}
              vacPrice={item.vacPrice}
            />
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

NOTES:
-When I log   console.log(`SingleVac: , ${props.id}_${props.vacImg}`) - it results in the correct filename for this vacation's img. but no image is showing, I get 404 error, and when trying to access it directly from the browser with the URL of the image, I get [object Object].
-My server runs on localhost:4000.
-my server.ts is in the same directory as Images folder (both under backend folder)
-I also tried adding the /backend directory before /Images - no luck there.

Comment: Did you make the `Image` folder accessible with `app.static`?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar Inside my server.ts I used server.use("/Images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "Images")));
I edited the code I've provided with more details about my server.ts

Comment: Try changing it to `server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/Images")))`;

Comment: @YoussoufOumar I did, no luck..

Comment: Did you also removed this `server.get("/Images/:image"` after doing as I said above?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar
I found a solution, to move the server.use(express.static) to the top of the server.ts file, above the routes.

It appears as middlewares should be placed BEFORE routes, since node works one by one, and if the routes need any response from the middleware (but mw is placed after routes), it won't work.
unless you use a next() function.

Thanks for trying to help Youssouf!

Comment: Hi DanWi! Glad you did find a solution, and you are welcome!